# how Read a particular Page from a doc or pdf file.

Tags: java, pdf, file-io

I have some  document of .doc and .pdf file and my requirement is to read a particular page from the .doc or .pdf file which i will provide at the run time .This can be possible by reading page by page and at the end of each page if i do numbering .but some i am getting some document where numbering is not their so how can i do that?

is their any api or any other logic so that i can fixed this problem?

hello all 
i have .DOC file but i am not supposed to read entire file instead i am given a page number. 
therefore i got to read only that particular page from the doc file. 
I am using apache.poi api.

```
     file = new File("c://doc/assignment/afternoon_24.doc");  
     FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

i need to read the page X of this file and write to a text file?

Comment: Concerning pdf files: There are multiple PDF libraries, and many of them allow for text extraction from individual pages. Are there any additional requirements? Licenses? Budget? Libraries already in use?

Comment: @mkl in our project,reading pdf is secondary requirement how to doc

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a missunderstanding: You can not read a DOC (or PDF) simply as an Inputstream and skip pages (unless you know and evaluate the fileformat). 
Both files have a format (encoding the formatting and meta info into some binary formats). Just try to open a PDF in notepad or another plain text editor. You will see it.

As mkl suggested: to access the contents of a DOC (or PDF) you need a library that can handle that fileformat. For Microsoft Office formats there is for example the open source library [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), for PDF there is for example [PDF box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) among others and [a full thread about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java). There are different libraries for each of the formats with different features and licensing models.